# Having trouble tracking the position of an object in Unity C#

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, position, transform, gameobject

I have a very strange problem I haven't been able to solve for a few hours. I am trying to trigger and event when two objects get close to each other. I've never had any trouble doing this in the past, but for some reason this time, the position of the objects I'm looking at appears not to be updating, and when I print() it returns the original start positions of the objects rather than their current position.

In the game window and the inspector I can see that the objects (Agents) are changing position. But the event is not being triggered because the code thinks the objects are in their original starting positions.

I have some weird natural languages features in my code, like an "a" class and a "the" class, which hold public variables and are present in the scene. The Self class "my" inherits from an Agent class with one variable Self class "my". The Self class is directly on the game object. The only reason I have Agent separate from Self is so that the player can take control of any Self class in the scene, without having to have it's own Self class.

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;

public class Brain : Agent {

    public List<Self> sight;
    public float time;

    void Start () {
        the = my.the;
        a = my.a;
    }

    void Update () {
        // set thinking interval
        if (time <= Time.deltaTime - 0.5) {
            time = Time.deltaTime;
            Think ();
        }

        // set a random destination based on current destination
        Vector2 randomVector = Vector2.one * Random.Range(-0.1f, 0.1f);
        my.destination += randomVector;
    }

    void Think() {

        print(FindObjectOfType<Agent>().transform.position); // a test that always returns the initial starting position rather than the current position (I don't know why)

        foreach (Self their in transform.parent.GetComponentsInChildren<Self>()) {

            if (their != my) { // don't perform this action on myself

                print (my.name + "'s position is... " + my.transform.position); // returning start position not current position
                print (their.name + "'s position is... " + their.transform.position); // returning start position not current position

                if (the.Distance (my.transform.position, their.transform.position) < my.vision && !sight.Contains (their)) {

                    Limb limb = (Limb)Instantiate (a.limb);
                    limb.transform.parent = my.transform;
                    limb.transform.localPosition = Vector2.zero;
                    limb.focus = their.gameObject;
                    sight.Add (their);

                }
            }
        }
    }
```

The limb is instantiating fine at the start of the game, for those objects that begin within the vision distance of each other, but this is supposed to update on an interval throughout the game.

Any help would be much appreciated. For further reference here are the other classes.

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class Grammar : MonoBehaviour {

    public A a;
    public The the;
}

using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class A : MonoBehaviour {

    public Limb limb;
    public Node node;
    public Link link;
}

using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class The : MonoBehaviour {

    public Grid grid;

    public Structure border;
    public Structure map;

    public Player player;

    public GameObject squareParent;
    public GameObject linkParent;
    public GameObject nodeParent;

    public Color red;
    public Color yellow;
    public Color blue;
    public Color orange;
    public Color green;
    public Color purple;
    public Color gray;
    public Color darkGray;
    public Color black;
    public Color white;

    public void NewColor(GameObject gameObject, Color color) { gameObject.GetComponent<SpriteRenderer> ().color = color; }
    public Vector2 HeadingFrom(float angle) { return new Vector2(Mathf.Cos(angle * Mathf.Deg2Rad), Mathf.Sin(angle * Mathf.Deg2Rad)); }
    public float AngleFrom(Vector2 heading) { return Mathf.Atan2 (heading.y, heading.x) * Mathf.Rad2Deg; }
    public Vector2 Relative(Vector2 heading, float z) { return (Vector2)(HeadingFrom(AngleFrom(heading) - z)); }
    public float Distance(Vector2 from, Vector2 to) { return (Heading(from,to)).magnitude; }
    public Vector2 Heading (Vector2 from, Vector2 to) { return to - from; }
    public Vector2 MidPoint (GameObject my, GameObject their) { return (my.transform.position + their.transform.position) / 2; }
}

using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class Agent : Grammar {

    public Self my;

    void Start () {

    }

    void Update () {

    }
}

using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class Self : Agent {

    public SpriteRenderer skin;
    public CircleCollider2D edge;
    public Rigidbody2D body;
    public Brain brain;

    public Square square;

    public float vision;
    public float speed;
    public float maxSpeed;

    public Vector2 restPosition;
    public Vector2 destination;
    public Vector2 gridPos;

    void Awake () {
        a = FindObjectOfType<A> ();
        the = FindObjectOfType<The> ();
        my = this;
        destination = transform.position;
    }

    void OnMouseDown() {
        the.player.transform.parent = transform;
    }
}
```

Comment: which variable holds your object which does not update the movement?

Comment: The "my" variable (Self) is the one I use to reference any script and the gameObject, and it is attached to the gameObject of course. So, I expect the behaviour to be that whenever I reference my.transform.position, that should give me the current position of the gameObject. I have tried my.gameObject.transform.position also, with the same result, it only returns the original starting position, even though in the inspector the gameObject is registering a change in position as it moves.

Comment: You do know that `Time.deltaTime` gives you the time that passed during completion of the last frame? If you're doing `if (time <= Time.deltaTime - 0.5)` its always going to be false and `Think()` is never going to be executed. Check out the Reference [link](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Time-deltaTime.html) EDIT: And stop using such shitty names for variables.

Comment: Aha! Thank you Officer Bacon, I have not implemented a timer before, and can see that that is probably the reason it is only updating Think() at the start. The natural language thing is a bit of an experiment as the program deals with very human characteristics, I thought it might be fun to try to have the code map on to that... it's a work in progress. Sorry to offend your code puritanism. I appreciate your answer.